# Missing Dependencies of Jboss 5 in Jboss 7

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I am trying to port a project from Jboss 5 to Jboss 7. I have these dependencies in Maven under dependency management in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-system-jmx</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-system</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-j2se</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

What would be the corresponding Jboss 7 dependencies?

It seems that the name of the groupid has changed to org.jboss.as but the included artifacts don't have the same names. Are they included in other artifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of JBoss 7 was completely rewritten since JBoss 5.

If you had dependencies on jboss system, you'll probably need to re-evaluate them to see why you needed them in the first place and what it could correspondend to in JBoss 7.

Start with the nexus search at:
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.jboss.as~~~~
You can do a classname search there as well.